# How to set WinEdt default encoding as utf8 no bom?

Tags: utf-8, tex

I download ctex which contains winedt as the default editor. I am Chinese and I want to change the default encoding of winedt from GBK to UTF-8, because I want to interactive with my linux documents.

I hava tried below operations:
Click 'options' -> 'preferences' -> 'unicode', Then set:
    'enable utf-8 format for modes': *;UTF-8;EDT;INI|UNICODE;UTF-7;ACP;OEM
    'enable ansi format for modes': ACP|UNICODE;UTF-8;UTF-7;OEM

After these operations, the encoding of the file I edit with winedt become 'UTF-8 BOM' not 'UTF-8 No BOM'. It gave me a obsession.